# Upload base64 image data to google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, base64, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading images as base64 to google cloud storage using nodejs/express.
But uploading sometimes gets successful and i can open the image on the storage but sometimes altho, uploading has been successful, the image is corrupted and i cant open the image on the cloud. Could anyone help me? Much appreciate it.
Here is my code.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const stream = require("stream");
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();

const serviceKey = path.join(__dirname, "./keys.json");
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: serviceKey,
  projectId: "my_project_id",
});
const bucket = storage.bucket("my_bucket_name");

bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(base64Image, "base64"));

const thumbFile = bucket.file("thumbs/" + id + ".png");
bufferStream
      .pipe(
        thumbFile.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            contentType: "image/png",
            metadata: {
              custom: "metadata",
            },
          },
          public: true,
          validation: "md5",
        })
      )
      .on("error", (err) => console.log("Error while saving thumbfile", err))
      .on("finish", () => console.log("Thumbfile saved."));
```

Comment: grab the image from storage and compare its bytes with the original in a hex editor

Comment: thank you, yes, the image size is not shown on google cloud. could you let me know why this happens?

Comment: hard to tell, base64Image is not defined in your code, you say some work some don't so guessing you left out some code? do some debugging

Answer (score 0):

If your're using the FileReader object to convert images to base64 string using the "readAsDataURL" function - please ensure that you remove the "data:image/png;base64," part of the string through `base64Image.split(';base64,').pop();`